# boost deadline_timer - max number of timers in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost, timer

Does anyone know what the max number of simultaneous boost deadline_timer instances can be created within a process in Linux?  I believe boost uses the Posix timer_create method.

Comment: I believe asio has used [`timerfd_create`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) for [some time now](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/3639)

Answer (score 1):

From the Linux [timer_create manpage](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html%20manpage):

```
The kernel preallocates a "queued real-time signal" for each timer created
using timer_create().  Consequently, the number of timers is limited by the
RLIMIT_SIGPENDING resource limit (see setrlimit(2)).
```

Use `ulimit -i` in bash to get or set RLIMIT_SIGPENDING. On my Ubuntu server, that limit defaults to 16382.